# HttpClient not throwing exception when using await on GetAsync

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm using the following code to get an endpoint and write it to a cache:

```
public async Task UpdateCacheFromHttp(string Uri)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Uri))
        return;

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(Uri);

    if ((response != null) && (response.IsSuccessStatusCode))
    {
        var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        WriteToCache(responseStream);
    }
}
```

The code is running on IIS.

If the endpoint can't be reached I'd expect GetAsync to throw an exception. Even with a Try-Catch, it never seems to fail. GetAsync never returns (I tried a 5 second timeout on the HttpClient, still didn't return).

This does throw an exception:

```
public Task UpdateCacheFromHttp(string Uri)
{
    var updateCacheTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Uri))
            return;

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = httpClient.GetAsync(Uri).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
            WriteToCache(responseStream);
        }
    }));

    return updateCacheTask;
}
```

I get the expected "Unable to connect to the remote server".

I suspect it has something to do with the code running in IIS, but why? How do I get it to properly throw the exception without the need to start a new task?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My intuition tells me that you're calling `Wait` or `Result` further up your call stack.

If that is correct, then you're causing a deadlock, as [I explain on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Answer (score 0):

As I encountered the same behaviour with no Exception being thrown, I created a sample to demonstrate the problem with a possible solution:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exam
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static async Task<string> GetWebPage(string uri)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute), HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // These two lines do not work - i.e. it terminates the application without any exception being thrown...
                //string s = await GetWebPage(@"https://www.dwd.de/DE/leistungen/klimadatendeutschland/klimadatendeutschland.html");
                //Console.WriteLine(s);

                // This works:
                Task<string> getPageTask = GetWebPage(@"https://www.dwd.de/DE/leistungen/klimadatendeutschland/klimadatendeutschland.html");
                getPageTask.Wait();
                if (getPageTask.IsCompleted)
                    Console.WriteLine(getPageTask.Result);
            }
            catch (AggregateException aex)
            {
                aex.InnerExceptions.AsParallel().ForAll(ex => Console.WriteLine(ex));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When you additionally change the URI to something like @"invalid https://...." you will retrieve the AggregateException.
Hope, it helps anyone :-)

Comment: Uncommenting the line `string s = await GetWebPage(...` should cause a compile-time error, because the calling method is not async. I.e. I highly doubt that it causes the application to terminate without any exception being thrown.

Comment: Hey Theodor, if you add "async" it works as described. I needed to remove "async" to not get the compile error, when the two marked lines are commented ;-)

Comment: Cordt if you add `async` to `void Main` you get an `async void`, which is [something to avoid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). The correct signature for an asynchronous [Main() entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) is `async Task Main()`.

Comment: Theodor, thanks for the clarification. I know that async void is to be avoided as it does not forward exceptions. I came across this thread because when I was preparing myself for the C# exam I encountered the termination of my program without any exception. So i googled and found this thread. I don't know exactly why this had happen, but now the same piece of code is running without termination. I can only guess that the loading of the page took longer than today and that's why it works.

Comment: Yeap, this is a reasonable explanation. Btw the `async void` methods are not like fire-and-forget tasks that have their exceptions unobserved. An exception thrown by an `async void` is rethrown on the captured `SychronizationContext`, or on the `ThreadPool` if their isn't any, so you are surely going to observe it (the process will be crashed). For this reason the `async void`s are sometimes called fire-and-crash.